# Group by and counting comparing two arrays of objects Java

Tags: java, group-by, java-8, counting, collectors

I have 3 classes: `Agency`, `Team` and `Agent`. An `Agent` belongs to a `Team` that belongs to an `Agency`.

I need to do a report counting how many agents I have on each `Agency`.
I don't have a database, just `ArrayList`s with the following data:

```
List<Agent> agents
List<Team> teams
List<Agency> agencies
```

On the `Agent` class, I have `getTeam()`, which has `getAgency()` (From `Team` class).

I was trying to do:

```
for (Agency ag : agencies) {
    for (Agent a : agents) {
        if (a.getTeam() != null) {
            if (a.getTeam().getAgency() == ag) {
               teste = "Agency from agent" + a.getTeam().getAgency().getCode() + "Agency from agency" + ag.getCode();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to count it separated for each `Agency`.

So I tried:

```
Map<String, Long> agentsAtAgency = 
    agents.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Agent::getTeam, Collectors.counting()));
```

But I can't get the agency from `Agent`, because I need `getTeam().getAgency()` and this Map doesn't allow me to do that.

Summarizing:

I have agency: A,B,C.

I have agents: X related to agency A, Y related to agency A, Z related to agency B.

I need to show: Agency A: 2 agents / Agency B: 1 agent / Agency C: 0

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You should use a lambda expression instead of method reference in this case.

This would allow you to group by `a -> a.getTeam().getAgency()` (or by some property of `Agency` having `String` type, since your output is a `Map<String, Long>`):

```
Map<String, Long> agentsAtAgency = 
    agents.stream()
          .filter(a -> a.getTeam() != null)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getTeam().getAgency().getName(),
                                         Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: How can I return the values as a String, please? If I want to show for each agency "Agency x has y agents"

Comment: @asr I was assuming `Agency` has a `getName()` property (or something similar) that returns a `String`. You can iterate over the entries of the output Map and print them in whatever formatting you like.

Comment: I'm getting null pointer exception, because not all my Agents has a team. This isn't a loop, how can I filter if (agent.getTeam != null) ?

Comment: Thank you so much, its working. I am returning System.out.println(agentsAtAgency); and getting {A=3, B=2, C=1}. How can I get those values from the map and put in on a String?

Comment: @asr `for (Map.Entry<String,Long> entry : agentsAtAgency) {System.out.println("Agency " + entry.getKey() + " has " + entry.getValue() + " agents");}`

Comment: Ive tried it already. I got the error on agentsAtAgency from the for "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable". I searched here, you missed the ".entrySet()" after agentsAtAgency. Sorry for so many doubts, it is my first time using Map. You helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: @asr Yes, I missed `entrySet()`. Sorry about that

Comment: `agentsAtAgency.forEach( (agency,count) -> System.out.println("Agency "+agency+" has " +count+" agents" );`